# Populate Select Field Based on Dynamic Selection

Tags: php, html, mysql

Pass variable from one dropdown to another with MySQL, PHP

I am having difficulty passing a variable from one dropdown field to another.

Here is my first dropdown. This does display correctly in querying the database to show the available states.

```
<tr>
   <td>State</td>
   <td><select name="state" id="state"><option value=''>Select</option>
      <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * from states";
          $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row->state . "'>" . $row->state ."</option>";
             }
          }
       ?></select></td>
</tr>
```

Based on the selection in the first dropdown, I would like to populate the second dropdown with cities for the selected state. I do not know how to pass the state variable to the second query.

Second dropdown:

```
<tr>
   <td>City</td>
   <td><select name="city" id="city"><option value=''>Select</option>
      <?php
          $sql = "SELECT * from cities";
          $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);
          if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 ) {
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)) {
                echo "<option value='" . $row->city . "'>" . $row->city ."</option>";
             }
          }
       ?></select></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't passing value from HTML to PHP and run PHP without page load. Try using jquery `$.get()` to get cities value of selected state and change cities dropdown `<select>` using jquery `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Chee, this helped me to move in another direction with jQuery. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
<tr>
   <td>City</td>
   <td><select name="city" id="city"><option value=''>Select</option>
                                <script>
$('#state').on('change', function(){
        var city = $(this).val();
        if(city){
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'ajaxData.php',
                data:'city='+city,
                success:function(html){
                    $('#state').html(html);
                }
            });
        }else{
            $('#city').html('<option value="">Select state first</option>');
        }
    });

</script></select></td>
</tr>
```

And here's my ajaxData.php file:

```
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $cities WHERE ".$_POST['city'].";
    $result = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        echo '<option value="">Select City</option>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
            echo "<option value='" . $row->city. "'>" . $row->city. "</option>";
        }
}
```